# Is there a single word or proper name for someone who struggles to wake up?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word or a different phrase that describes a person as a heavy sleeper or as somebody who struggles to wake up in the morning?

I don't mean a technical phrase for a health condition, just the common "I don't want to get up yet" kind of sleeper.

**EDIT**: I'm new to this stack exchange so I'm not sure if it's proper to do so, but I want to explain what I intend to use this for. Perhaps it'll help in finding the word/phrase.

I'm looking to name an alarm clock application. The app is geared towards waking up heavy sleepers or people who struggle in the morning. They're not lazy and spending all day in bed. They're wanting to get up (hence why they set the alarm) maybe for work or an appointment but struggle with somnolence (awesome word) in the morning.

Comment: I'm open to any words that could mean this, but I am kind of leaning towards it being a person who never really woke up but turned off their alarm. It may not be by choice (choosing to be lazy), but may be because of sleepiness or general lack of awareness.

Comment: There are slang terms like "bedbadger" or "bed hugger" also. I'm not sure how common they are though.

Comment: ermanen, that seems judgmental. There can be different reasons for struggling to wake up or get up in mornings.

Comment: Teenager. It's now well documented that [they can't get up in the morning](http://www.newscientist.com/article/mg21829130.100-why-teenagers-really-do-need-an-extra-hour-in-bed.html#.UyDfp1ZldyE)

Comment: I could deliver a couple dozen catchy phrases for your alarm clock app, but my doing so would not come cheap. (I am only partially kidding.) Being an inventive, idea-driven critter, I'll come up with a dozen decent ideas before another person who THINKS he's a hotshot idea person comes up with one.  Some people in need of creative ideas think initially there's nothing to it, and then they get stuck. Rather than admitting defeat and going to a REAL idea person, they will sometimes say, dismissively, "Hey, ideas are a dime a dozen; I'll come up with one tomorrow." I say, "Maybe; maybe not!" Don

Answer (score 6):

[Sleepyhead](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sleepyhead)
or [Slugabed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slugabed) any good?

Comment: I was going to recommend _sleepyhead_ myself. Good one.

Answer (score 2):

How about a "somnolent"?  It appears to have the double advantage of being entirely original (not listed in noun form in the dictionary) and conveying the meaning well.  :)

Comment: Related: *Somnus,* the Roman god of sleep.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Dysania](http://wiktionary.academic.ru/197129/dysania)** The state of finding it hard to get out of bed in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

We call that a *bed-slug* in my house.